# Yeoman install component manually

Tags: javascript, yeoman, bower

I want to use a library in my yeoman project that is not in the bower repo. What is the best way to integrate the library into the yeoman project structure? This library requires jquery to be loaded first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just put the folders of client side javascript libs into my app/scripts/vendor folder and reference them to load in the index.html

Make sure you put the script tag inside these comment blocks

```
<!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
```

and

```
<!-- endbuild -->
```

in order to have them minified and merged into one script file on build.